# MediaGrop Middleware Aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram, middleware, media, aiogram

How do I write a middleware to forward media groups to aiogram 3?
Users in the group send a command to the bot. The bot will send them a message, to which they must respond with a media group, which the bot will then forward to everyone who uses the bot. But since sending media groups for a bot is several messages, I need a middleware to collect them all and then send them to users

I tried to use the code that is already available for aiogram 2, but I don't understand how to redo it for version 3

Comment: Take a look at the changes between AIOGram 2 and AIOGram 3, and change the references in the code(if any).  That is the general gist of what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Media middleware:

```
import asyncio
from typing import *
from aiogram import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery

class MediaMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, latency: Union[int, float] = 0.01):
        self.medias = {}
        self.latency = latency
        super(MediaMiddleware, self).__init__()


    async def __call__(
        self,
        handler: Callable[[Union[Message, CallbackQuery], Dict[str, Any]], Awaitable[Any]],
        event: Union[Message, CallbackQuery],
        data: Dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Any:

        if isinstance(event, Message) and event.media_group_id:
            try:
                self.medias[event.media_group_id].append(event)
                return
            except KeyError:
                self.medias[event.media_group_id] = [event]
                await asyncio.sleep(self.latency)

                data["media_events"] = self.medias.pop(event.media_group_id)

        return await handler(event, data)
```

Usage:

```
@router.message(F.media_group_id != None)
def on_media_group_id(message: Message, media_events: List[Message] = []):
    # message - last sended message
    # media_events - all events with the same media_group_id
    ...
```